# Get location header from M-SEARCH Response

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement the [DIAL protocol](http://www.dial-multiscreen.org/dial-protocol-specification) in Android using java.

Following the protocol implementation, I have to do an M-SEARCH request. For this I use the following code:

```
private final static String DISCOVER_MESSAGE = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        + "HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900\r\n" + "MAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\n"
        + "MX: 120\r\n" + "ST: urn:dial­multiscreen­org:service:dial:1\r\n";
```

And the actual method:

```
// Set the MulticastSocket to DIAL implementation.
// See the Discover Message for its full implementation.
final int port = 1900;
InetAddress multicastAddress = InetAddress.getByName("239.255.255.250");
MulticastSocket usedSocket = new MulticastSocket(port);
usedSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
usedSocket.setSoTimeout(130000);
usedSocket.joinGroup(multicastAddress);

byte[] requestMessage = DISCOVER_MESSAGE.getBytes("UTF-8");
DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(requestMessage,
           requestMessage.length, multicastAddress, port);

// Send the package.
usedSocket.send(datagramPacket);

// Listen for the response.
byte[] buf = new byte[9000];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
usedSocket.receive(packet);

response = new String(packet.getData());
```

The problem I run into now, is that according to the specification:

> An SSDP/UPnP server receiving an M­-SEARCH request with the Search Target defined above shall respond as defined in Section 1.3.3 of [1](http://www.dial-multiscreen.org/dial-protocol-specification), including a LOCATIONheader containing an absolute HTTP URL for the UPnP description of the root device. The host portion of the URL SHALL either resolve to an IPv4 address or be an IPv4 address.

But all I am getting in the responded package, seems to be same data I had sent.

This may be due to my incorrect reading of the response, I am not sure. How can I get the location header from this M-SEARCH response?

Could this be caused by a faulty M-SEARCH request?

Answer (score 0):

Been doing this in my Android app myself
main difference I see with mine (which works and is based of a M-SEARCH example I found online somewhere)

```
   StringBuffer mSearchMessage = new StringBuffer();
    mSearchMessage.append("M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    mSearchMessage.append("HOST: " + SSDP_IP + ":" + SSDP_PORT + "\r\n");
    mSearchMessage.append("ST:urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1\r\n");
    mSearchMessage.append("MAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\n");
    mSearchMessage.append("MX: 2\r\n");
    mSearchMessage.append("\r\n");
```

while yours, especially the ST line is
    "MX: 120\r\n" + "ST: urn:dial­multiscreen­org:service:dial:1\r\n";

So there seems to be some hyphens missing.. I suspect you might have fixed this by now, but that is at least one part that could cause a problem as I think the ST means it looks for that string it self on the device.